# PyCharm does not see source root

Tags: python, pycharm

I have marked the folder as `source root` but PyCharm still is not able to import from there without warnings. In the given picture I am trying to import from the `models` to the `document.py`. How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why isn't `api` the source root when you have source in `app` as well? +I don't think source root is correct importable path. Because you have to be level higher to actually see the folder. Even more reason to have `api` as root

Comment: @h4z3 You should write the same as an answer then I will be able to mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're inside a folder, you don't really see where you are. Source root *contains packages* and it's not a package on its own, so to be able to import `models`, you gotta make its parent folder (`api`) a source root.

This is also better because you have code *next to* `models`, in `app`, and it's part of the source as well. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Models is not a package. Add an empty `__init__.py` file on it

Comment: I already have added the init.py file.

Comment: Show the content of the folder. Pycharm is not detecting it as a package because it doesn't have the black dot on the folder icon

Comment: Sorry, I can't paste images to the comments but it's a package, and the only reason the dot is not shown is that it's already marked as a source root. If I unmark that the dot still will be able to be shown. Just a tricky UI.